# bash: how do you return file extensions?

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to write a script to return just the extension of the input file name. For example, `textfile.txt`
should return `txt`.

I'm new to Linux and bash, and I'm trying to learn how to write basic scripts. Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Comment: What is the extension of `linux-4.2.3.tar.xz` file that you can download from [kernel.org](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.2.3.tar.xz)? What is the extension of `/bin/bash` file that is most certainly available at your system? You see, the concept of "file extension" is pretty alien in Linux. The part after the dot carries very little significance for the system - it is rather a cue for the user on what he might expect from that file. And that cue may lie or be wrong.

Answer (score 36):

The shell, bash for example, has many [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) features. One of them lets you remove everything up to a given pattern:

```
${VAR##GLOB}
```

The syntax above removes everything from the variable `$VAR` until the first match of the glob `GLOB`. So, to print a file's extension without its name, you could do:

```
$ file="file.txt"
$ echo ${file##*.}
txt
```

Note that this can also deal with more than one "extension":

```
$ file="file.new.txt"
$ echo ${file##*.}
txt
```

If you don't want that, use one `#` instead, which will remove the shortest match instead of the longest:

```
$ echo ${file#*.}
new.txt
```

Now, to run this on all files in a directory, you could do:

```
$ ls 
file.avi  file.pdf  file.png  file.txt
$ for file in *; do echo "$file : ${file##*.}"; done
file.avi : avi
file.pdf : pdf
file.png : png
file.txt : txt
```

And, for the sake of completeness, you can also get the file name without its extension using `${file%.*}`:

```
$ for file in *; do echo "$file : ${file##*.} : ${file%.*}"; done
file.avi : avi : file
file.pdf : pdf : file
file.png : png : file
file.txt : txt : file
```

Comment: this doesn't work for things like foo/.git/bar/baz I guess you could do                                                                              
                echo test.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'

Comment: @PaulM what do you mean? That's a file with no extension, what would you expect to get from that?

Comment: echo "/foo/var/.git/foo/bar.bz" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'

==>> bz

Comment: @PaulM `file="/foo/var/.git/foo/bar.bz"; echo "${file##*.}"` : `bz`. I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 4):

With [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02):

```
$ x="textfile.txt"
$ echo ${x##*.}
txt
```

The `${parameter##word}` pattern removes the largest prefix that matches `word` (everything except the file ending).

Comment: This prints the original filename if the file has no extension.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple bash script that could do what you want would be the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$1" | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'
```

The script is invoked as `script.sh test.txt`, and what it does is

- it prints `$1` to stdout. `$1` is the first parameter given to the script, in this case `test.txt`.
- the stdout output of `echo` is piped to stdin for `awk` which splits the string (`test.txt`) on `.` and then it prints the last element of the split (`txt` in this case).

Just a small remark, this can be done with a one-liner because it's a pretty simple task:

```
echo test.txt | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: You need to add quotes around `$1`, or you risk breaking file names that contain spaces etc.

Comment: this doesn't work for things like foo/.git/bar/baz

I guess you could do 


echo test.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

my_file=`basename "$1"` # get full file name as a script  parameter and strip the path
my_extension="${my_file##*.}"
my_file="${my_file%.*}" # will return base file name before the extension

echo "$my_file"
echo "$my_extension"
```

Run:

```
./script.sh index.html
```

Output:

```
index
html
```

More info: [Shell Parameter Expansion | gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 3):

To do so, there are several caveats to take into account:

- The `foo.d/bar` file has no extension, it's not a `foo` file with a `.d/bar` extension.
- you may also want to consider that `.bashrc` has no extension
- The `.` and `..` special directory files should probably be treated specially and considered to not have any extension.
- what's the extension for `file.tar.gz`? `gz` or `tar.gz`? What about `holiday.picture.jpg` or `bash-4.4`?
- What should you return for `foo.d/`? Empty or `d`?

Here, I'd do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for file do
  case ${file##*/} in
    (?*.*) ext=${file##*.};;
    (*) ext=;;
  esac
  printf '%s\n' "$ext"
done
```

Comment: Excellent answer handling also the usual caveats and useful code especially as a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'll thrown in some more options in case you have `sed` or Perl installed:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ext=$(<<<"$1" sed -n 's/^[^.]*\.//p')
printf "Extension: $ext\n"
ext=$(<<<"$1" perl -ne 's/^.*?\.//&&print')
printf "Extension: $ext\n"
exit 0
```

- `s/^[^.]*\.//p` in `sed` and `s/^.*?\.//&&print` in `perl`: try to substitute the shortest sequence of characters not `.` followed by a `.` character at the start of the string; if the substitution could be made, print the result of the substitution;

```
% bash script.sh file.bin
Extension: bin
Extension: bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. In Unix/Linux (and MacOS) the "filename extension" is just informative (if that much). You can perfectly have a Perl script called `photo.gif`, or a GIF file named `poem.txt`. Or even a file called `some.txt.png`.

Comment: It's just as informative in MS Windows, it's just that in there the default shell program makes stronger assumptions about the extension--content pairing, and should there be a mismatch between naming and content, the whole thing usually just starts shouting errors, the poor thing.