# Copy files to new directory only if name of file is in an array

Tags: files, osx, zsh, ruby, oh-my-zsh

I'm not much of a `zsh` buff but I imagine this should be an easy layup for someone:

I can bulk copy files from `sourcedir` to `targetdir` with the following:

```
$ find sourcedir -type f -exec cp {} targetdir \;
```

How might I only `cp` so if the file name matches one of:

```
top directory
  fileA            <= directories have same name as single file they enclose
    fileA.pdf                    <= file to move
  another file
    another file.pdf             <= do NOT move
  still133another4544file
    still133another4544file.pdf  <= file to move
```

Literally thousands to go through but only need to move a select few which I have the names for and can put in a file or enter directly into script.
Could remain a simple shell script' I'd also accept Ruby.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Do you only want to copy those three files? Do you want to copy any file with one of those three names?Any file matching one of those three names (`thisisfileA.pdf`, for example)? Does this need to be recursive? What shell script? What you show is a single command, there is no script.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but this is ttill not clear. What's the difference between the files you want to move and the ones you don't want to? Do you want the directories copied as well, or only the files? Why are you mentioning bash if you're using zsh? Please [edit] your question and i) remove bash if you're not using it; ii) give us an example of the source target directory & file structure and iii) what you would want to see in the target directory.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here's the sample tree I created:

```sh
{   pwd
    for   d in ./*/
    do    cd "$d"
          printf '\t%s\n' "${d#??}"
          printf '\t\t%s\n' *
          cd ..
    done
}
```

---

```
/tmp/top
        another file/
                another file.pdf
        fileA/
                fileA.pdf
        otherdir/
                1
                2
                3
        stillanother4544file/
                stillanother4544file.pdf
```

Now obviously you don't need to do any of that - I created the tree to mirror your example tree and just added a few outliers.

But here is what I do recommend you do:

```sh
pax -rwis'|^./\([^/]*\)/\(\1\....\)$|\2|' -s'|.*||' . ../tgt
```

That calls the POSIX-standard `pax` utility in `-r`ead/`-w`rite mode - direct copy mode, basically. In copy mode `pax` doesn't create a `tar` archive as it usually would in `-w`rite mode, but instead directly copies all files found in its `[...pattern...]` argument[s] - which is here just `.` for the tree rooted in the current directory - and/or the names of which it reads on its stdin - which is empty in this case - to the directory named as its last argument - which is here `../tgt`.

Now, I know, you don't want to move the whole tree. Much of that is handled with the `-s`ubstitution arguments. You can rename output files based on regular expression `sed`-style statements as I do here. I use two `-s`ubstitution statements. The first one renames all input matches for:

```
./dirname/samename.???
```

...to...

```
samename.???
```

...on output thereby flattening the output tree to put all copied files in `../tgt` directly. If you would rather keep the `./dirname/` parent directories for each you can replace the `\2` part of the first `-s`ubstitution to just `&`.

Once a filename has been successfully matched and modified by a `pax` `-s`ubstitution it is not tried again for any remaining `-s`ubstitution arguments, and only those files which could not yet match are tried for any remaining rename regular expressions. This means that all files rooted in the current directory with pathnames that fit the type:

```
./dirname/samename.???
```

...are successfully selected and stripped of all but their last pathname components with the first `-s`ubstitution statement and all *other* files rooted in the current directory are substituted completely away with the second `-s|.*||` `-s`ubstitution. This is because `pax` drops from its processing list any filename which substitutes to a null string.

Once `pax` has processed all of that it has one last duty to fulfill before it can actually copy the selected files - and that is the `-i`nteractive rename option I've specified, and which I think is probably right up your alley.

From `man pax`:

> `-i`
>
> - Interactively rename files or archive members. For each archive member matching a *`pattern`* operand or each file matching a file operand, `pax` will prompt to `/dev/tty` giving the name of the file, its file mode, and its modification time. `pax` will then read a line from `/dev/tty`. If this line is blank, the file or archive member is skipped. If this line consists of a single period, the file or archive member is processed with no modification to its name. Otherwise, its name is replaced with the contents of the line. `pax` will immediately exit with a non-zero exit status if *`EOF`* is encountered when reading a response or if `/dev/tty` cannot be opened for reading and writing.

---

```sh
ATTENTION: pax interactive file rename operation.
-rw-r--r-- Oct 17 04:30 stillanother4544file.pdf
Input new name, or a "." to keep the old name, or a "return" to skip this file.
Input > .
Processing continues, name unchanged.

ATTENTION: pax interactive file rename operation.
-rw-r--r-- Oct 17 04:30 another file.pdf
Input new name, or a "." to keep the old name, or a "return" to skip this file.
Input >
Skipping file.

ATTENTION: pax interactive file rename operation.
-rw-r--r-- Oct 17 04:30 fileA.pdf
Input new name, or a "." to keep the old name, or a "return" to skip this file.
Input > .
Processing continues, name unchanged.
```

So of the six files in the current directory, only those three make it through to the `-i`nteractive rename prompts, and of those three only two make it to `../tgt`:

```
ls -l ../tgt
```

---

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Oct 17 04:30 fileA.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Oct 17 04:30 stillanother4544file.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have those file names saved in an array and none of them contains `|` (as that would need to be escaped but not worth bothering - see alternative below) you could simply join the elements of the array and use the result as glob:

```
myarr=( file1 file2 ... fileN )
lst=${(j:|:)myarr}
cp -v -- **/($~lst) targetdir
```

e.g. with these files in random places under my `/tmp`:

```
caxZN.gif
e8ApF.gif
div2k.js.lzo
cmp2jz.ini
```

and their names saved in an array, this is the result:

```
cp -v -- **/($~lst) targetdir
```

```
‘tmp/div2k.js.lzo’ -> ‘targetdir/div2k.js.lzo’
‘tmp/other dir/e8ApF.gif’ -> ‘targetdir/e8ApF.gif’
‘tmp/other dir/one two/cmp2jz.ini’ -> ‘targetdir/cmp2jz.ini’
‘tmp/some dir/caxZN.gif’ -> ‘targetdir/caxZN.gif’
```

---

Alternatively, this time assuming they're listed in a file, one file name per line, you could read the lines in an array and then use [glob qualifiers/*e*string](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) and [modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to glob/select only the file names in your array:

```
mylist=(${(f)"$(<list_of_files)"})
cp -- **/*(.e_'(($mylist[(Ie)$REPLY:t]))'_) targetdir
```

practically `.` selects only regular files (add `D` if your list contains dotfiles) and `e_'expression'_` returns only those file names for which `expression` is true, in this case if their *basename* (`$REPLY:t`) [is an element of the array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags) `mylist`, e.g.:

```
print -rl -- **/*(.e_'(($mylist[(Ie)$REPLY:t]))'_)
```

```
tmp/div2k.js.lzo
tmp/other dir/e8ApF.gif
tmp/other dir/one two/cmp2jz.ini
tmp/some dir/caxZN.gif
```

---

Sure, all of the above assume `zsh`.
Anyway, your own solution also works, as long as you take the time to write the file names and pass the right options to `find` e.g.

```
find . -type f \( -name caxZN.gif -o -name e8ApF.gif -o -name div2k.js.lzo -o -name cmp2jz.ini \) -exec cp -- {} targetdir \;
```

Comment: Good stuff, thanks!  Do you know if it's possible to send `find . -type f` a list of names (say a text file with one filename per line)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any `find` flavor/version that accepts a list of file names. You could do something like `mylist=($(sed -e '1i\' -e '-name' -e '1!i\' -e '-o\' -e '-name' input_list))` then `find . \( "${mylist[@]}" \) -exec cp -- {} targetdir \;` This assumes sane file names in your `input_list` (no spaces or funky chars). You could also ask a separate question _re: find and + list of names_ (someone else might come up with a better idea).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find sourcedir -type f -name 'file?.pdf' -exec cp {} targetdir \;
```

should match only those files matching that pattern.

Comment: that should be `-name 'file[AEW].pdf'` - `file?.pdf` matches more than what the OP wanted.

Comment: I sthought that these were only examples. If the OP really only wanted those three then you are of course right.

Comment: `… -exec cp -t targetdir {} +`

Comment: @Costas OP used the /osx tag, OS X apparently [does not have these option](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, each of your directories only has a single file and you want to move that file if it is in your list. If so, you can do:

```
while read -r file; do cp sourcedir/*/"$file" targetdir; done < list.txt
```

If you also need to copy the directories, you could read the files, [strip the file extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236034/22222) to get the directory name and copy that:

```
while read -r file; do cp -r sourcedir/"${file%.*}" targetdir; done < list.txt
```